# Factor the polynomial completely and find all its zeros. $P(x)= x^4+2x^2+1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Factor the polynomial completely and find all its zeros. State the multiplicity of each zero. 
$P(x)= x^4+2x^2+1 $

I'm stuck on this problem, can anyone show me the steps on how to factor it out completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If we let $u = x^2$, we can write our polynomial as $u^2 + 2u + 1$, which factors as $(u + 1)(u + 1)$. Replacing $u$ with what it means, we find that

$$P(x) = (x^2 + 1)^2$$

Now note that $x^2 + 1 = x^2 - i^2$ is a difference of squares.